# PHPUnit doesn't find Framework.php

Tags: phpunit, mamp

It's now 2 days that I've been trying to get phpunit working on my OSX. I'm running php from a MAMP installation.

I have installed it via PEAR with all dependencies. 
The phpunit --version command is working and displays :

```
$ phpunit --version
PHPUnit 3.6.10 by Sebastian Bergmann.
```

But when I run a test from the command line it shows :

```
Warning: require_once(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Framework): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Users/magalie/Sites/HelloWorld/HelloWorldTest.php on line 3

Call Stack:
    0.0028     632128   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0078    1161288   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:46
    0.0078    1162016   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
    0.1109    1793352   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
    0.1109    1793352   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
    0.1115    1837832   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
    0.1126    1983864   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:78
    0.1127    1983984   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
    0.1128    1994704   9. include_once('/Users/magalie/Sites/HelloWorld/HelloWorldTest.php') /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'PHPUnit/Framework' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/PEAR:/usr/lib/php') in /Users/magalie/Sites/HelloWorld/HelloWorldTest.php on line 3

Call Stack:
    0.0028     632128   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:0
    0.0078    1161288   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/phpunit:46
    0.0078    1162016   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:130
    0.1109    1793352   4. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->getTest() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:150
    0.1109    1793352   5. PHPUnit_Runner_BaseTestRunner->loadSuiteClass() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:104
    0.1115    1837832   6. PHPUnit_Runner_StandardTestSuiteLoader->load() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/BaseTestRunner.php:168
    0.1126    1983864   7. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::checkAndLoad() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Runner/StandardTestSuiteLoader.php:78
    0.1127    1983984   8. PHPUnit_Util_Fileloader::load() /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:79
    0.1128    1994704   9. include_once('/Users/magalie/Sites/HelloWorld/HelloWorldTest.php') /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/PHPUnit/Util/Fileloader.php:95
```

Here is the configuration from pear

```
Configuration (channel pear.php.net):
=====================================
Auto-discover new Channels     auto_discover    1
Default Channel                default_channel  pear.php.net
HTTP Proxy Server Address      http_proxy       <not set>
PEAR server [DEPRECATED]       master_server    pear.php.net
Default Channel Mirror         preferred_mirror pear.php.net
Remote Configuration File      remote_config    <not set>
PEAR executables directory     bin_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin
PEAR documentation directory   doc_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/doc
PHP extension directory        ext_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions
PEAR directory                 php_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/
PEAR Installer cache directory cache_dir        /var/folders/qH/qHdMKNY5GsywPNMBPX-T7U+++TI/-Tmp-//pear/cache
PEAR configuration file        cfg_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/cfg
directory
PEAR data directory            data_dir         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/data
PEAR Installer download        download_dir     /var/folders/qH/qHdMKNY5GsywPNMBPX-T7U+++TI/-Tmp-//pear/download
directory
PHP CLI/CGI binary             php_bin          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/bin/php
php.ini location               php_ini          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
--program-prefix passed to     php_prefix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
--program-suffix passed to     php_suffix       <not set>
PHP's ./configure
PEAR Installer temp directory  temp_dir         /var/folders/qH/qHdMKNY5GsywPNMBPX-T7U+++TI/-Tmp-//pear/temp
PEAR test directory            test_dir         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/tests
PEAR www files directory       www_dir          /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/www
Cache TimeToLive               cache_ttl        3600
Preferred Package State        preferred_state  stable
Unix file mask                 umask            22
Debug Log Level                verbose          1
PEAR password (for             password         <not set>
maintainers)
Signature Handling Program     sig_bin          /usr/local/bin/gpg
Signature Key Directory        sig_keydir       /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/pearkeys
Signature Key Id               sig_keyid        <not set>
Package Signature Type         sig_type         gpg
PEAR username (for             username         <not set>
maintainers)
User Configuration File        Filename         /Users/magalie/.pearrc
System Configuration File      Filename         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf
```

and phpunit is run from /usr/lib/php which is part of $PATH

And this is the content of my HElloWorldTest.php file, I have already tried with or without the php extension to Framework file with no success.

```
<?php
require_once 'HelloWorld.php';
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework';
///Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/

class HelloWorldTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function test__construct()
    {
        $hw = new HelloWorld();
        $this->assertType('HelloWorld, $hw');
    }

    public function testSayHello()
    {
        $hw = new HelloWorld();
        $string = $hw->sayHello();
        $this->asserEquals('Hello World!', $string);
    }
}
```

I have already tried to uninstall and reinstall phpunit, with no luck. And looking in the PHPUnit directory, there is no Framework.php file.

SO what am I doing wrong ? 
Is there anybody who had the same issue ? How did you solve it  ?
This is driving me crazy, and I have the impression to run in circles ...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to load PHPUnit in your test. The `phpunit` executable takes care of setting up its own autoloader. Delete this line:

```
require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework';
```

Answer (score 0):

> You don't need to load PHPUnit in your test. The phpunit executable takes care of setting up
> its own autoloader. Delete this line:
>
> > require_once 'PHPUnit/Framework';

This worked for me.

Alternatively, if you have a lot of existing tests, possibly not even written by yourself, you can create an empty file called "Framework.php" and place it in your PHPUnit directory.